# joining of two list<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I have two list of strings of different lengths.For example

```
List <string> Mksnos={"Toyota",
                     "Honda is Good",
                     "Innova is very good" }


List <string> GdsDscr={"Toyota is a very good brand
                       and it is costly",
                       "The carmaker's flagship sedan is now here in its hybrid avatar. It is brought to... The Honda Accord Hybrid has been launched in India" }
```

[image]

Here there result that I would achive, any suggestion?

Comment: Read your question to yourself a couple of times...try not to fill in the blanks.  If you can't even figure out what you're asking, how would you expect us to figure out how to answer it?

Comment: You've given us requirements but not shown what you've done to solve it.  Find the larger of the two lists.  Use a `for` loop to loop through the lists. Build a new list or whatever structure your output is supposed to be in. Figure out what do do to avoid an index out of bounds exception. Come back when you're stuck on one of those steps.

Comment: I have tried many times its not so easy as u guys say

Comment: @David I have read my question better u try to understand

Comment: @user1716097 you seem to misunderstand how Stack Overflow works.  My obligation to try to understand a bad question is not nearly as large as your obligation to make a bad question easy to understand.  After all, you are asking for the community's help, not the other way around.  You have not shown any efforts so far and D Stanley has given you some excellent advice.  You should take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indexes of the two lists are the same, then you can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> Mksnos = new List<string>()
    {
        "Toyota",
        "Honda is Good",
        "Innova is very good"
    };

    List<string> GdsDscr = new List<string>()
    {
        "Toyota is a very good brand and it is costly",
        "The carmaker's flagship sedan is now here in its hybrid avatar. It is brought to... The Honda Accord Hybrid has been launched in India"
    };

    var joinedLists = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Mksnos.Count(); i++)
    {
        var nksnosValue = Mksnos[i];
        var gdsDscr = GdsDscr.Count() > i ? GdsDscr[i] : string.Empty;

        joinedLists.Add(nksnosValue, gdsDscr);
    }

    foreach (var joined in joinedLists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{joined.Key}: {joined.Value}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick answer but lists are of different lengths

Comment: @user1716097 I thought you were going to complain this answer doesn't print borders for you:)

Comment: No No It works many many thanks.But what to do if it contains many lists not two

Answer (score 0):

The Zip Linq function can basically achieve exactly what you're after - although  it outputs up to the size of the smallest enumerable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx

But instead, we can just pad out the second list like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> Mksnos= { "Toyota", "Honda is Good", "Innova is very good" };
List<string> GdsDscr= { "Toyota is a very good brand and it is costly",
                       "The carmaker's flagship sedan is now here in its hybrid avatar. It is brought to... The Honda Accord Hybrid has been launched in India" };

var numberOfMissingValues = Math.Max(Mksnos.Count - GdsDscr.Count, 0);
var paddedGdsDscr = GdsDscr.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfMissingValues).Select(i => " ")).ToList();

var lines = Mksnos.Zip(paddedGdsDscr, (make, comment) => $"{make}: {comment}");

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

If you're looking for multiple lists (for some fixed number), you could do something like:

```
var comments = firstComments.Zip(secondComments, (b, c) => $"{b} - {c}")
var outLines = makes.Zip(comments, (make, comment) => $"{make}: {comment}");
```

Put obviously the questions around what to do around mismatched list sizes is unanswerable without a more detailed spec!